# Bash replace white space and end of string with another string

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace

Hi I hope someone can help with an issue,

I need to get certain values from a text file and convert them in something neat for document output. I have the following code to obtain the values:

```
values=$(awk '/PARAMETER/ {getline ; getline; print ($(NF-6) )}' $array)
```

This gives me for example a string: `9.00 5.00 9.00`

Now I want to convert that string into: `9.0m,5.0m,9.0m`. So ignore the second decimal and add `m,`. The values string can vary in length and values, but always has two decimals.

How to do this quickly!?

Basically this the text I need to analyze. Particularly I need one Z value of subset 1 and one Z value of subset 2:

```
MODEL PARAMETERS :
Project : Report
Dataset : xxx

Number of subsets    : 2
Total number         : 4

Subset number    : 1
Subset name      : xxx_sub1
Number           : 4

 NR   TYPE                       X(m)      Y(m)    Z(m)   Volume Pressure   CluNo Activ  Group
 ---  ---------------------    ------    ------   -----  ------- --------   ----- -----  ------
   1  Type text                  0.00    -10.40    9.00   2000.0    500.0       0     0     1
   2  Type text                  0.00     -9.60    9.00   1000.0    500.0       0     1     1
   3  Type text                  3.00    -10.40    9.00   1200.0    500.0       1     1     1
   4  Type text                  3.00     -9.60    9.00    800.0    500.0       1     1     1

Subset number    : 2
Subset name      : xxx_sub2
Number           : 4

 NR   TYPE                       X(m)      Y(m)    Z(m)   Volume Pressure   CluNo Activ  Group
 ---  ---------------------    ------    ------   -----  ------- --------   ----- -----  ------
   1  Type text                  0.00     10.40   15.00   2000.0    500.0       0     0     1
   2  Type text                  0.00      9.60   15.00   1000.0    500.0       0     1     1
   3  Type text                  3.00     10.40   15.00   1200.0    500.0       1     1     1
   4  Type text                  3.00      9.60   15.00    800.0    500.0       1     1     1

Units : 
   Coordinates      : meter
   Volume           : cubic cm
   Pressure         : pascal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%.1fm",$i)}7'
```

the above one-liner may help you. check the test:

```
kent$  echo "2000.44 234.88 9.00 5.00 9.00"|awk -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%.1fm",$i)}7'
2000.4m,234.9m,9.0m,5.0m,9.0m
```

Comment: I would hate to pipe awk to awk. Isn't there a way to fold in OP's original awk script into this awk script to make one complete awk program?

Comment: @kojiro I won't do `awk|sed|awk|....` either. but OP has only given us the output of his command (awk). I cannot see his original input. I just did some work based on his output. If he gave more info, the should be better solution.

Comment: @Cnoobplusplus the non-zero number (7 in this case) in awk to perform the default action: print the current line.

Comment: Ah okay. It must possible to put format printing in the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` and `paste`:

```
$ values="9.00 5.00 9.00"
$ while IFS=, read val; do printf "%.1fm\n" $val; done <<< $values | paste -sd,
9.0m,5.0m,9.0m
$ values="1.1000 2.4 3.400 42"
$ while IFS=, read val; do printf "%.1fm\n" $val; done <<< $values | paste -sd,
1.1m,2.4m,3.4m,42.0m
```

Comment: Why not just `… printf %.1fm,' "$val"; done; echo` instead of the paste? It's not pure bash right now…

Comment: @kojiro Because it'd add a trailing `,`.

Comment: @kojiro Because of `paste`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I mean, yes

Comment: You could always do `printf '%.1fm,' $values; printf '\b \n'`. *runs away laughing maniacally*